# Setting up alerts for provisioning events in Azure

Tags: azure

i'd like to put an alert in in my tenancy that notifies me whenever a public ip address is provisioned. Is this possible?
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing, but you can create a policy for a subscription to deny the provisioning of public IPs. So, unless you remove this policy, no one will be able to create this type of resource.

Access the preview portal: https://preview.portal.azure.com

Select Subscription -> Policies -> Add assingment

[image]

The GUI is in preview (as of the time of this post), not the feature. Policy management is GA using PowerShell.